# How does peewee handle automatic creation of primary keys?

Tags: python-3.x, peewee

I am trying to figure out how peewee handles the creation of primary keys when creating tables where the `id` column is not specified. My goal is to write an database connector for SQL Server via SQL Relay, but i think this question may apply more generally for anyone trying to understand how peewee works.

In the `SchemaManager` object, there is a method called `_create_table` that deals with the table creation.

```
def _create_table(self, safe=True, **options):
    is_temp = options.pop('temporary', False)
    ctx = self._create_context()
    ctx.literal('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ' if is_temp else 'CREATE TABLE ')
    if safe:
        ctx.literal('IF NOT EXISTS ')
    ctx.sql(self.model).literal(' ')

    columns = []
    constraints = []
    meta = self.model._meta
    if meta.composite_key:
        pk_columns = [meta.fields[field_name].column
                      for field_name in meta.primary_key.field_names]
        constraints.append(NodeList((SQL('PRIMARY KEY'),
                                     EnclosedNodeList(pk_columns))))

    for field in meta.sorted_fields:
        columns.append(field.ddl(ctx))
        if isinstance(field, ForeignKeyField) and not field.deferred:
            constraints.append(field.foreign_key_constraint())

    if meta.constraints:
        constraints.extend(meta.constraints)

    constraints.extend(self._create_table_option_sql(options))
    ctx.sql(EnclosedNodeList(columns + constraints))

    if meta.without_rowid:
        ctx.literal(' WITHOUT ROWID')
    return ctx
```

I see the composite key creation code in there, but i don't understand how a simple primary key is added.

The main problem i am running into in my work is that the primary key is created without an `IDENTITY` property (which is not surprising because peewee doesn't support SQL Server). Therefore, without the `IDENTITY` property, it is impossible to create model objects in the database using `Model.create()`.

Any help with this is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround for this issue, which is to add an non-auto-incrementing primary key to the model using `IntegerField(primary_key=True)`. Then i use `Model.save(force_insert=True)` to insert instead of update when creating a new object.

Comment: This is documented: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#manually-specifying-primary-keys